# How to add images and cards to dialogflow chatbot in android

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I've built a chat bot for android using dialog flow but when I integrated my bot with android, cards and images stopped working. How can I make them work in android?

Comment: Following the rules of the site, I would advice you to add some code you have tried into your question else it will be flag and remove.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is difficult to understand exactly what problem you're having, or what "stopped working". If you can update your question to illustrate what was working, isn't now, and provide code that shows how you're attempting to do it, we may be better able to help. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)